Skopt does not create the skopt.bat File in a windows environment
`C:\Users\pillo\OneDrive\Dokumente\GitHub\skopt>python setup.py install
Making .bat files for Windows
Making .bat files for Windows
Making .bat files for Windows
running install
C:\Users\pillo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!
....
error: file 'C:\Users\pillo\OneDrive\Dokumente\GitHub\skopt\bin\skopt.bat' does not exist
C:\Users\pillo\OneDrive\Dokumente\GitHub\skopt>`

It seems like you are using older method.  setup.py install is deprecated and it's no longer creating .bat files correctly on Windows.
You can use following methods now.
Use Pip for installation:
cd C:\Users\pillo\OneDrive\Dokumente\GitHub\skopt
pip install .

or
Install directly from GitHub
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize.git

